# Is calling spin_lock_irqsave, instead of local_irq_disable followed by spin_lock, the same for a per-prorcessor struct?

Tags: c, concurrency, linux-kernel, locking, spinlock

Consider the following kernel code

```
local_irq_disable();
__update_rq_clock(rq);
spin_lock(&rq->lock);
```

`rq` is a pointer to a per-processor `struct` (i.e; not subject to SMP concurrency). Since `rq` will never be accessed in an another place after calling `local_irq_disable` (because `rq` is used by only a single processor and disabling local interrupts means no interrupt handlers will run on that CPU), then what is the point of embedding `__update_rq_clock` between the previous functions? In other words, what difference does it make from the following, which disables interrupts and takes the lock in a single call, given that `rq` is safe in both cases inside `__update_rq_clock` either locked or not?

```
spin_lock_irqsave(&rq->lock, flags);
__update_rq_clock(rq);
```

Comment: The first code is updating before taking the lock, so the lock has no effect.  The second code saves the previous irq state, and presumably restores it later.  So they are very different.

Comment: @stark again it doesn't matter, the result of calling `local_irq_disable` or `spin_lock_irqsave` is the same: they will both disable interrupts. The only difference on the interrupts level is that `spin_lock_irqsave` remembers which interrupts were enabled and which were disabled so we can later restore them as they were before, while `local_irq_enable` will just enable everything. But I don't care about this part, my question doesn't talk about enabling interrupts but about the meaning of locking `rq`, its safety inside `__update_rq_clock` and the order of calling those functions.

Comment: The difference is that critical section (lock-protected) is **smaller** in their case than in yours one. If some function does NOT require lock-protection, why should one call it under the lock?

Comment: @Tsyvarev but, again, it doesn't matter! It's the same thing, `rq` is fundamentally protected in both cases, `rq` is not subject to SMP concurrency because it's a per-processor struct, which means the only concurrency risk comes from interrupt handlers, but interrupts handlers are disabled by `local_irq_disable`, which means that `rq` has no risk of being accessed from another place (neither a processor nor an interrupt handler!), so delaying `spin_lock(&rq->lock)` until after  `__update_rq_clock(rq)` doesn't result in a smaller critical section because actually there is no critical section!

Comment: which means we actually get nothing from delaying the `spin_lock` so we could have just used `spin_lock_irqsave` and it will absolutely result in the same thing!

Comment: "because actually there is no critical section!" - Eh? The part of code between `spin_lock` and corresponded `spin_unlock` is a lock-protected **critical section**. And moving the call to `__update_rq_clock` from outside of this section to inside it actually makes the critical section longer.

Comment: @Tsyvarev again, there is no concurrency issue in the above code after disabling IRQs, that's why I said critical region doesn't exist. That is to say, after disabling IRQs, taking the `rq->lock` isn't mandatory at all and it doesn't have any effect on the correctness of the code, whether taken or not! That's why I assumed my snippet of code is equivalent to the kernel's (ignoring IRQ restoration in which case calling `local_irq_enable` followed by `local_irq_enable` solves the problem). People are emphasizing too much on the IRQ stuff while I don't care about it at all!

Comment: If you know that interrupts are enabled, which the original code that calls `local_irq_disable` assumes, then in your replacement code you can call `spin_lock_irq` instead of `spin_lock_irqsave`.

Comment: @IanAbbott I agree, good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost: the two examples you show have different semantics: `local_irq_disable` does not save the old state of IRQs. In other words, when the corresponding `local_irq_enable` function gets called, it will *forcibly* re-enable IRQs (whether they were already disabled or not). On the other hand, `spin_lock_irqsave` does save the old IRQ state, so it can later be restored through `spin_unlock_irqrestore`. For this reason, the two pieces of code you show are very different, and it doesn't make much sense to compare them.

Now, coming to the real problem:

> Since `rq` will never be accessed in an another place after calling `local_irq_disable` (because `rq` is used by only a single processor and disabling local interrupts means no interrupt handlers will run on that CPU)

This is not always true. There isn't a "magic barrier" which stops CPUs from accessing another CPU's per-CPU data. It is still possible, and in such case extra care must be taken by means of a proper locking mechanism.

While per-CPU variables are usually meant to provide fast access to an object for a single CPU, and therefore *can* have the advantage of not requiring locking, there is nothing other than convention that keeps processors from digging around in other processors' per-CPU data ([quote](https://lwn.net/Articles/22911/)).

Runqueues are a great example of this: since the scheduler often needs to migrate tasks from one runqueue to another, it certainly will need to access two runqueues at the same time at some point. Indeed, this is probably one of the reasons why `struct rq` has a `.lock` field.

In fact, doing an rq clock update without holding `rq->lock` seems to be considered a bug in recent kernel code, as you can see from [this lockdep assertion](http://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L206) in `update_rq_clock()`:

```c
void update_rq_clock(struct rq *rq)
{
    s64 delta;

    lockdep_assert_held(&rq->lock);

    // ...
```

It feels like the statements you show in your first code snippet should be re-ordered to lock first and then update, but the code is quite old (v2.6.25), and the call to `__update_rq_clock()` seems to be *deliberately* made before acquiring the lock. Hard to tell why, but maybe the old runqueue semantics did not require locking in order to update `.lock`/`.prev_clock_raw`, and thus the locking was done afterwards just to minimize the size of the critical section.

Comment: Having a `lock` field in the structure doesn't mean that accessed to **all** fields in this structure are needed to be lock-protected: It could be that the lock is required only when protect **some fields** of the structure, but accesses to other fields doesn't require the lock. As for `lockdep_assert_held` call inside `update_rq_clock`, it actually requires `update_rq_clock` to be called with the lock taken. But.. the question post is about `__update_rq_clock` function, not about `update_rq_clock` one. (While I have failed to find version of the Linux kernel which has `__update_rq_clock`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev good point about the lock, could surely be needed for something else, I'll strip that part from the answer. As per the `__update_rq_clock` function it seems quite old and I was only able to find it from 2.6.23 to 2.6.25, and it looks like that old code still assumed the lock to be held anyway (thought no lockdep assertion was present).

Comment: Oh, such old kernel... It seems [that code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.25.1/source/kernel/sched.c#L3921) which the question post is talking about. And according to the comment above - "Do the rq-clock update outside the rq lock" - the function is **intentionally** called without the lock protection. I understand that the comment doesn't mean correctness (it is known that old Linux kernels really have problems with concurrency), but nevertheless.

Comment: @Tsyvarev interesting, thank you, I've added context around that. Looks strange, but I suppose old rq semantics did not warrant a lock to update the rq clock fields. Either that, or that was an actual bug.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli thanks for the reply. I upvoted but not sure whether to accept as an answer or not yet! Let's discuss a little more. I absolutely know that `local_irq_disable` and `spin_lock_irqsave` are different in the fact that the latter saves the IRQ state to be restored later, while the former does not, and enables all IRQs upon calling `local_irq_enable` (I have already mentioned that in my reply to @Tsyvarev's comment above).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli However, bear in mind that, in the same way you reasoned about per-cpu variables, nothing, except convention, prevents you from calling `spin_unlock` followed by `local_irq_enable` after initially taking a lock with `spin_lock_irqsave`, although care must be taken. But let's not discuss in such a way. After all, everything is possible if someone knows what he is exactly doing.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Let me put it in this way: let's say that I don't care about interrupts and let's assume that, in this case, restoring the previous IRQ state with `spin_unlock_irqrestore` (which also releases the lock) or calling 'local_irq_enable' is the same (just assume! But it is certainly correct in many situations). Will my two snippets of code be equivalent in this case?

Comment: I also agree, with you, as hinted in my previous comments, that per-cpu variables are only conventionally accessed by their designated processor. However, in my short experience with the kernel, I've not yet seen a code that violates the convention.

Comment: @KarimManaouil *almost*. They would be equivalent if the update was after the lock in the first snippet, and if you ignore the fact that one of the two variants saves the IRQ state. In such case the two snippets would be functionally equivalent (you still need locking anyway and disabling IRQs is not enough as I say in my answer). Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yes sure, I understand you perfectly. If we assume that we were in a perfect world where per-cpu variables are accessed only by their designated processors then the snippets will be the same and taking the lock before calling `__update_rq_clock` would pretty much be the same thing functionally speaking, and it won't make the critical region longer as there is already no critical region after disabling the IRQs anyway (but assuming the per-cpu variable is not accessed by other CPUs, which is unfortunately not the case (eg; load-balancing -> thread migration)! ).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli your last statements in your answer are also a little bit confusing! It doesn't make sense to postpone holding the lock until after the update but then manipulate the runqueue inside the update itself!!! And honestly, I don't think it was a bug since this is a very major and central piece of code that was probably reviewed thousands of times by all seasoned kernels devs, it's just unbelievable they would miss such a thing!.

Comment: @KarimManaouil yeah exactly. In a perfect world where the per-CPU var is really only used by its CPU you wouldn't need locking at all, just disable local irqs when needed. Though the right amount of locking would still improve performance even in such case, since continuosly disabling IRQs only to access variables is pretty overkill and would stop all threads from being scheduled even if they don't need to interact with the variable.

Comment: @KarimManaouil it does make sense to postpone locking untill reallt necessary if the semantics of the lock are defined in a certain way: e.g. if the lock is only needed for manipulating other fieds, and not the clock. In my last statement I said that I assume that the locking is done after the update_rq_clock just because updating the clock did not need locking in old kernels. And yes, you're surely right that it is *not* a bug. I was just saying "either it's this way or it's a bug" (hence, it must be this way).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli things are much clearer now! Thanks a lot for your answers and have a nice day my mediterranean *amico*!